# My pc sends 14000 arp requests in 5 minutes to a single pc on the network

Tags: windows, networking, wireshark, arp

I am currently checking my network traffic on my home network using wireshark.

I have noticed that my pc is continuously arp requesting a pc on the network with 192.168.1.20 but like 14000 times in 5 minutes which is ridiculous of course.

The pc that he is requesting ARP from isn't even on but something has to create these arp requests.

How can I make this stop?

[image: but like 14000 times in 5 minutes]

Comment: To make it stop, enter a static ARP mapping on .16, so it knows the MAC address for .20. That doesn't solve the root cause, but it will probably stop the ARP flood.